# Unknown receiver 'AFHTTPRequestOperation' ; did you mean 'AFHTTPRequestSerializer'

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am learning `AFNetworking` kit. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial). Now I stuck at comment 2 see code below `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

I imported `AFNetworking` using cocoapods.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)jsonTapped:(id)sender{
    // comment 1
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // comment 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // comment 3
    self.weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // comment 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // comment 5
    [operation start];
}
```

**Now getting error at compile time see screen shot:**

[image]

Comment: The issue is that you are using a tutorial for AFNetworking 2.0 when you have imported the AFNetworking 3.0. Since you used CocoaPods, you can specify the version of AFNetworking to make it works, else here is the migration guide: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Larme is right, have a look at the similar issue at  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3125  also you must import  like #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

Comment: tried changeing to 2.0 didnt work , i think AFHTTPRequestOperation is not there , any other alternative for this implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
- (void)apiRequestForPOSTWithServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName andParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameter withCompletion:(void(^)(id response, BOOL isSuccess))completion
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, serviceName];
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        completion(responseObject,YES);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        completion(error,NO);
    }];
}
```

Happy coding...!!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you included `AFNetworking` properly inside your project before you import any of the `AFNetworking` class. Probably you have not imported the kit properly.

Dont use `UIAlertView` which is deprecated `iOS` 9 use `UIAlertController` see code below.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"text mssg" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
    // Ok action code here 
}];
UIAlertAction *otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Other" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
    // Other action code here 
}];

[alert addAction:okAction];
[alert addAction:otherAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The UIAlertView/UIAlertController is irrelevant here: you don't know what is the minimal iOS target of the OP. So you should stick to the first paragraph of your answer only.

Comment: @Cœur, dont think so this is irrelevant after-all it was a correction, if op has found his ans in first para then all goes fine.